# How do you transfer all tables between databases using SQL Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, export

When I right click on the database I want to export data from, I only get to select a single table or view, rather than being able to export all of the data. Is there a way to export all of the data?

If this is not possible, could you advise on how I could do the following:

- I have two databases, with the same table names, but one has more data than the other
- They both have different database names (Table names are identical)
- They are both on different servers

I need to get all of the additional data from the larger database, into the smaller database.

Both are MS SQL databases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being that both are MS SQL Servers, on different hosts... why bother with CSV when you can setup a [Linked Server instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778%28SQL.80%29.aspx) so you can access one instance from the other via a SQL statement?

1. Make sure you have a valid user on the instance you want to retrieve data from - it must have access to the table(s)
2. Create the Linked Server instance
3. Reference the name in queries using four name syntax:

   ```
   INSERT INTO db1.dbo.SmallerTable
   SELECT *
     FROM linked_server.db.dbo.LargerTable lt
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                       FROM db1.dbo.SmallerTable st
                      WHERE st.col = lt.col)
   ```

Replace `WHERE st.col = lt.col` with whatever criteria you consider to be duplicate values between the two tables.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a very good tool by Redgate software that syncs data between two databases.

I've also used [SQL scripter](http://www.sqlscripter.com/) before to generate a SQL file with insert statements that you can run on the other database to insert the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click on the database, under the Tasks menu, you can use the Generate Scripts option to produce SQL scripts for all the tables and data.  See this [blog post](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/21/sql-server-2005-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects/) for details.  If you want to sync the second database with the first, then you're better off using something like Redgate as suggested in mpenrow's answer.